# ElasticSearch Aggregations with script doc_values

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation, elastica

I have a field "location_facet", which is a strig with mapping

```
"location_facet": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "include_in_all": true
               },
```

In this field I have location_ids and I would like to aggregate on them by the query. Also I want to become some information by the aggregation, that's why I would like to execute a script, for example I want to become the name of the city, but there is always an error coming:

```
"aggs": {
        "location_radius": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "location_facet",
                "size": 10,
                "script": "doc[\"location_name\"].value"
            }
        }
},


"type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc[\"location_name\"].value] using lang [groovy]"
```

I have actually this implementation with Facets:

```
$tagFacet = new \Elastica\Facet\Terms("location_radius");
$tagFacet->setField('location_name');
$tagFacet->setAllTerms(true);
$tagFacet->setSize(100);
$tagFacet->setScript(
                "doc['location'].empty ? null : ceil(doc['location'].arcDistanceIn".$unit."(".
                $entries->getLocationLatitude().", ".
                $entries->getLocationLongitude().")) + '|' + doc['location_name'].value
            + '|' + doc['location_id'].value"
            );
```

What I am doing wrong?

If I test this one:

```
"aggs": {
        "location_radius": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "location_facet",
                "size": 10,
                "script": "doc['location'].empty ? null : ceil(doc['location'].arcDistanceInKm(51.2249429, 6.7756524))"
            }
        }
    },
```

I get the error:

```
"type": "script_exception",
               "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc['location'].empty ? null : ceil(doc['location'].arcDistanceInKm(51.2249429, 6.7756524))] using lang [groovy]",
               "caused_by": {
                  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                  "reason": "Negative position"
               }
```

Solution: All the doc fields I can use need to be also "index": "not_analyzed".

Comment: have you enabled `groovy script` in `elasticsearch.yml`?

Comment: Yes, everything is enabled.

Comment: Can you add `caused By` in error when you are running first query

Comment: The whole problem was, that all the doc fields I can use need to be also "index": "not_analyzed".